# Does any $f(x)$ which for large $x$ grows slower than any power of $x$ necessarily satisfy $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$?

Tags: limits

The title is essentially the question. Intuitively I would await that any function $f(x)$, which for large $x$ grows slower than any power of $x$, must necessarily satisfy

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

This holds at least for prominent examples like $\ln(x)$ and $\sqrt{x}$. But I don't know of a statement that it holds in general. Does anyone know or have a proof or counter examples?

Thanks for help!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that $f$ should also be strictly monotonically increasing, for large $x$, and also that it should be smooth ($C^\infty(\mathbb R)$).

Comment: What do you mean explicitly?

Comment: Is $f$ increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $f$ is differentiable (otherwise $f'(x)$ is meaningless).

Assuming the limit exists, it must be $0$.

Otherwise, if $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=L >0$$
then there exists $x_0 >0$ such that for $x>x_0$ necessarily
$$f'(x) > \frac{L}{2}$$This implies that $$f(x)=f(x_0)+ \int_{x_0}^x f'(t) \mathrm dt>f(x_0)+\frac{L}{2}(x-x_0)$$
which contradicts our hypothesis that $f$ grows slower than $x$.

However, nothing ensures that the limit exists. As a counterexample, you could consider
$$f(x) = \int_0^x |\sin t|^t \mathrm dt$$

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the detailed answer! The counter example you show is monotonically increasing, but not strictly monotonically. But I suppose the situation wouldn't change, if I would only consider strictly monotonically increasing functions, right? (They should also be $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ actually.)

Comment: Actually my last counterexample is strictly monotonic. Anyway, one can construct a $C^{\infty}$ function which is positive, has no limit as $x \to \infty$ but whose improper integral is convergent. Then, any of its primitives is a counterexample to your problem.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you so much for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

take function which has unit steps with unit derivative at increasingly large intervals. Limit doesn't exist, function grows as slow as you like.